# Syslog-ng format-json not working

Tags: json, templates, syslog-ng

I'm desperately trying to send a message as JSON to a PHP script.

```
destination d_php {
program("/usr/bin/php -f /data/htdocs/log.php" template("$(format-json)\n")  ) ;
};
```

The php script is fine. Using simple macros works well, but the "format-json" function does always return this:

> error in template: $(format-json)

I tried everything I could find in the documentation, but all response I get is "error in template".  The official docs [(link)](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.3-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.3-guide-admin-en/html/reference-template-functions.html#template-function-format-json) even use 2 different spellings, not very promising.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. Apparently, syslog-ng is split into separate packages on Ubuntu (12). I had to install `syslog-ng-mod-json`.

It's really a shame that syslog-ng doesn't give the slightest hint that the function is missing or unknown, instead of some general error.

Answer (score 0):

the format-json and format_json syntax should both work, hyphens and underscores are equivalent in syslog-ng. 
As for the actual problem, have you tried setting the scope parameter of format-json, like "$(format_json --scope selected_macros)"? By default, it is empty, which means there is nothing to format.

HTH,

Regards,

Robert Fekete

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling from the source, you shall install json-c library first (yum install json-c-devel).